# Migration from postgresql 8.4 to postgresql 9.0, postgis 1.5 involved

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Im migrating from 8.4 to 9.0, in pg8.4 i have postgis 1.5.1 and in 9.0 im just installed 1.5.2.

I decided to dump the postgis databases before the pg_upgrade command, and delete them, planning to create my new postgis_template and then create the databases:

```
pg_dump -C -h host -U postgres -f databasegis.dump databasegis
psql -U postgres < databasegis.dump
```

But I have errors :

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/liblwgeom": No such file or directory
ERROR:  function public.st_text(boolean) does not exist
```

What can i do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just find the best method, I used a script in postgis package called /usr/share/postgresql-9.0-postgis/utils/new_postgis_restore.pl This path my be different in your systems but only got a few duplicate primary key errors.

Answer (score 3):

This method worked.

1. Create a new database.
2. Install PostGIS 1.5  (the install files should be in
   `share/contrib/postgis-1.5`).
3. Then restore your data on top.
4. You should then get errors that the functions already exist and they
   will be skipped.  You may get some errors too about the liblwgeom, but those
   you can ignore since they represent functions long ago deprecated that got
   taken out of postgis-1.5.

Answer (score 0):

liblwgeom was renamed to postgis in version 1.4. Are you sure you are updating from 1.5?
If you are migrating a major version you should use a 'hard upgrade':
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html#upgrading

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS wiki helped me to do a clean hard upgrade from postgresql 8.3 with postgis 1.3.3 to postgresql 9.2 with postgis 2.0
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiWinUpgrade

Comment: hello can you provide a little more information in upgrading the 8.3 with 1.3.3 to postgres9.2 +postgis 2.0... i am in the same issue right now. thank you